# bootstrap-sass, Confusion that define white-space twice time

Tags: css, bootstrap-sass

```
code {
   padding: 0;
   color: inherit;
   white-space: pre;              // first time
   white-space: pre-wrap;        // why do this twice?
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
}
```

it's in `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_code.scss`

why not just define `white-space: pre-wrap`, from my point of view, it works well.
Does it work for some special purpose?

Answer (score 2):

`pre-wrap` is not availabe in all browsers and `pre` is its backup.

Comment: get it , I check the documentation more carefully and do find the answer on  [CSS|MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space), Thank U